# How to properly use 'for..in' list comprehension inside Coffeescript object indentation?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript, list-comprehension, idioms

I'm just getting started with Coffeescript, so I may be asking something really trivial, but this "bug" recently tripped me up:

```
class Foo
  toJSON_1: ->
    title: 'toJSON_1'
    items: i for i in [1..5]

  toJSON_2: ->
    items: i for i in [1..5]
    title: 'toJSON_2'

  toJSON_3: ->
    items: (i for i in [1..5])
    title: 'toJSON_3'

foo = new Foo
console.log(foo.toJSON_1())
console.log(foo.toJSON_2())
console.log(foo.toJSON_3())
```

I would have considered all of these equivelant, but look what happens with `JSON_2`:

```
{ title: 'toJSON_1', items: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ title: 'toJSON_2' }
{ items: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], title: 'toJSON_3' }
```

It took a while to debug, because I was following along with a tutorial using notation `JSON_1`, but in my code the list comprehension was not the last item (i.e. `JSON_2`), until I stumbled upon testing `JSON_3`.

Can someone explain to me why the CoffeeScript parser works with this way? And what is the proper idiom in the general case? Should I always wrap list comprehensions inside parens? Sounds like a bug waiting to happen to always assume there will only be one list comprehension and it will be at the end of the object declaration.

Maybe this is just a peculiar situation of a parser rule I'm not aware of...?

**EDIT:**

Playing with the compiler and generated Javascript some more, it looks like it's enough to wrap the code in `{}` brackets for Coffeescript to do the *right thing*:

```
 toJSON_2: ->
   {
     items: i for i in [1..5]
     title: 'toJSON_2
   }
```

I guess my question boils down to:

- is it more idiomatic to use the `{}` brackets or put parentheses
  around the list comprehensions?
- is this "unpredictable" behavior a bug?
- if not, why not?

Comment: That first `toJSON` should be `toJSON_1`, I presume? Also on terminology, these things are called "list comprehensions".

Comment: Fixed the typos. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's recommended to wrap comprehensions in parenthesis when building arrays, because `items = (item for item in list when x is y)`.

In `toJSON_2` the first line is being interpreted as

```
{ items: i } for i in [1..5]
```

You can't blame coffeescript for that, as the intent is not clear. My advice is to follow a simple guideline: **Anything that would confuse a human will very likely confuse the parser**.

That includes wrapping expressions in parenthesis, using explicit `return`s, brackets for object literals, temporary variables and whatever you need to make your intentions clear in code.

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed `items: i for i in [1..5]` was interpreted as `LHS: RHS`, where `RHS` was everything to the end of the line. This clears it up, and I will be sure to wrap comprehensions in parenthesis in the future.

Answer (score 1):

A consequence of fixing [#1871](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1871) and [#1903](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1903) prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my opinion as a programmer but not as one who has actually used CoffeeScript yet (looking into it fairly deeply is as far as I've gone so far): when programming, your general endeavour should be to make the meaning of your code as obvious and unambiguous as you can (though there can be other important things too, so this won't always be the most important goal).

When you hit yucky regions like that (which some CoffeeScript people will know about and some won't—in this case, I happen to have read of it in doing my research on CoffeeScript before trying to use it), the curly braces make it *much* more obvious and distinctly unambiguous. Whereas with the other, you're left with a fragile structure which a beginner will make a seemingly entirely innocuous change to but which will break it completely (and you might not realise it, and debugging will then be *very* difficult).

Comment: I agree with you. Since uncovering this behavior, I will end up using `{}` brackets in my code. When first posting I was unaware of the brackets solution. But the question still remains:  when I read `items: i for i in [1..5]` I expect a list to be returned and bound to `items`. It was quite a surprise for me when `JSON_1` and `JSON_2` did not act the same way. I'm leaving this question open in hopes that someone more familiar with idiomatic CoffeeScript can tell me and future readers if this is a recognized "issue" and what is considered idiomatic code/best practice.